# Dragonfly and Short URLs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dragonfly-gem

I'm using Dragonfly in a project that returns a large stream of photos and was looking to optimize the URLs. I'm currently getting image URLs like:

http://localhost:3000/media/BAhbCFsHOgZmSSJgZmRlL2ZkZTAxYzQ0LTM4Y2UtNGU0ZS1iOWRlLWUwZmUxNWUwN2JmMC83Mzk1NmZlMC05ZTA5LTQzNWUtODUyMC00MzFlYzQxMzQ1OTQvb3JpZ2luYWwuanBlZwY6BkVUWwg6BnA6CnRodW1iSSIMMjQweDI0MAY7BkZbCTsHOgxjb252ZXJ0SSIQLXF1YWxpdHkgODAGOwZGMA/240x240.jpg

Which is over 256 bytes. I'd like something like:

http://localhost:3000/media/1024/240x240_medium.jpg

That is conforming to:

```
/media/:id/:format
```

How would I go about adding this when using Dragonfly and Rails such that `:format` maps to a chain of operations and `:id` is used to find the model or image? Thanks!

**Edit:**

I've added custom `Mime::Type`for each of the formats I need and have the following working:

```
# config/routes.rb
match "/photos/:id/:style", to: "photos#show", as: :media

# app/controllers/photos_controller.rb
def show
  @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.jpg { cache('public', 86400); redirect_to @photo.url(params[:style], 'jpg') }
    format.png { cache('public', 86400); redirect_to @photo.url(params[:style], 'png') }
    format.gif { cache('public', 86400); redirect_to @photo.url(params[:style], 'gif') }
  end
end

# app/views/photos/show.html.erb
<%= image_tag media_path(id: @photo.id, style: 'small', format: 'png') %>
```

However this results in a `302` for each image (but otherwise works fine). Is it possible to handle this as a render or somehow do an internal redirect (i.e. not require the client to make duplicate requests)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you shouldn't need to use a controller action - you can use a dragonfly endpoint - see http://markevans.github.com/dragonfly/file.URLs.html#Routed_Endpoints

e.g.

```
match '/photos/:id/:style.:format' => Dragonfly[:images].endpoint { |params, app|
  Photo.find(params[:id]).image.thumb(params[:style]).encode(params[:format])
}
```

or something like that
(haven't tried the above code but it'll be something along those lines)

Answer (score 1):

I've ran into a similar situation where the client needed a short url for downloadable pdfs.

Building on Mark's answer and looking at the [dragonfly docs](http://markevans.github.io/dragonfly/rails/#custom-endpoints) I came up with this:

```
#file.rb
class File < ActiveRecord::Base
  dragonfly_accessor :pdf
end

def pdf_link
  return "/pdf/#{self.filename}.pdf"
end  

#routes.rb
get '/pdf/:filename' => Dragonfly.app.endpoint { |params, app|
  File.where(filename: params[:filename]).first.pdf
}
```

It's not a direct answer to the question, but maybe it can still help someone looking for a way to shorten urls in dragonfly